# Is set_time_limit() global or only for the current running script?

Tags: php, timeout

I've got a very ugly page where I've had to set max timeout to 2 minutes in PHP for the moment. I'm using the `set_time_limit()` function, but from the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) I wasn't clear how global the "setting" is.

This blurb seems to imply it's limited to the specific script:

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

Basically I want to double check, setting this one-time in one script doesn't affect the max run time for *any* other script at all, does it? Running any other page will still have the default timeout? No other page (in fact no other function) requires this timeout.

Comment: Note that you can easily test this by writing two scripts which you expect to time out and only calling `set_time_limit()` in one of them, and then trying to load them both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only for the currently running script.

Answer (score 2):

It will only affect the current script and no other page